# Error when trying to request data with Delta Exchange API ? I am new to Python and API, so cannot find a way to resolve the error

Tags: python, rest, algorithmic-trading

I am new to Python and wanted to try out how API works and ultimately build a basic trading bot. I have an account in Delta Exchange. I created and connected to API which all went well. But when I requested for details like `get_product()` or `get_assets()`, I am getting error. what am I doing wrong here?

**https://github.com/delta-exchange/python-rest-client**
*This is a Github guide for using this API if it helps*

I am hiding the API key and secret for safety reasons, I know this a basic question.

```
from delta_rest_client import DeltaRestClient
import requests

delta_client = DeltaRestClient(
base_url='https://testnet-api.delta.exchange',
api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', #hiding for privacy
api_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #hiding for privacy
)

product = delta_client.get_product(27)
response = delta_client.get_assets()
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\fahee> & C:/Users/fahee/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/fahee/Desktop/Programming/Delta Exchange/testbot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fahee\Desktop\Programming\Delta Exchange\testbot.py", line 10, in <module>
    product = delta_client.get_product(27)
  File "C:\Users\fahee\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\delta_rest_client\delta_rest_client.py", line 73, in get_product
    response = self.request("GET", "/v2/products/%s" % (product_id), auth=auth)
  File "C:\Users\fahee\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\delta_rest_client\delta_rest_client.py", line 64, in request
    res.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\fahee\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 960, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://testnet-api.delta.exchange/v2/products/27
```

Comment: "I am getting error".  So what is it?  Post the traceback.

Comment: @MarkTolonen sorry, now i have posted the traceback. hope you can help.

Comment: What happens if you call `get_assets` first?  Is 27 a valid product_id?  Are you sure your key and secret are correct, since it says you are unauthorized?

Comment: it's not python problem , it's either your username and password wrong or api url isn't correct

Comment: The calling get_assets() first doesn't change the error. 
27 is valid product id of BTCUSDT. 
My api key and secret cannot be wrong because i directly copied it from Delta exchange. 
It could be the url. I got the url from a guide. But i am not able to find the url in official documentation. It might be because i am new to reading documentations or something. Can you spot the url from this guide?
https://docs.delta.exchange/#introduction

Comment: It was indeed the url problem. The url given above is only for paper trading, hence i should not give any value for api key or api secret. But i need to do real trading. Can you help me with url to connect to real and not paper trading account??

Comment: @FaheemSameer If you read the docs the first piece of information you are given is the API endpoints which for production is `https://api.delta.exchange/v2` https://docs.delta.exchange/#ApiSection

Comment: Thank you Mr Alex B. Really apreciate your help